# Compile c++11 in a docker gcc:5 image

Tags: c++, c++11, docker, gcc, gcc5

My Dockerfile uses `FROM gcc:5`, runs apt-get update and installs CMake v3.9 via `wget`. My top-level `CMakeLists.txt` has `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` but that doesn't seem to convince gcc to compile using C++11 as I get the following error:

```
/ifeature.hpp:51:42: error: 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
     virtual float compare(const std::shared_ptr<IFeature>& feature) const = 0
                                      ^
```

I tried adding variations of `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")` with `libstdc++`, `gnuc++11` etc. but the compiler does not recognize them. I also tried `add_compile_options(-std=c++11)` to no avail. I also tried apt-get upgrade gcc but that didn't help either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You do include the `<memory>` header file?

Comment: On an unrelated note, why do you pass the shared pointer *by reference*? The normal use-case is to pass it by value, or the whole "shared" thing won't really work.

Comment: Hi There. Thank you. This is embarrassing but that was it. I had not included <memory>, given that I use a different compiler on my own machine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I pass the shared pointer by *reference* when I want to avoid adding another reference count to the shared_ptr itself. Is that a bad practice?

Also, I apologize that it took some time for me to reply. It is 4:30 AM here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference and in the interest of anyone who may encounter this page, I should update that just as @some-programmer-dude mentioned in the comment, simply including `<memory>` resolved the error shown in my question.

Given that my original development environment was different from the one in my Docker image and the code was written with different compiler, I had to resolve a few similar issues (missing include files) to satisfy `gcc-v5` requirements.